# getting request timeout in every request with http.request() in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

i am using nodejs http.request method to post some data to external API. I test like this:

```
var options={
hostname:'www.google.com',
port:80,
method:'POST'
};

var req=http.request(options,function(res){
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });


});
//console.log(req);
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);

});
```

This whole is wrapped inside a express servers post route.
But in console it always says connection timeout after a certain period. I am clueless.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply creating a `request` object. You have to send it too. Use `req.end()` to actually send the request.

```
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();  //add it
```

Comment: now i get this: 
c:\lms>node server.js
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
STATUS: 411
HEADERS: {"server":"AkamaiGHost","mime-version":"1.0","content-type":"text/html"
,"content-length":"222","expires":"Fri, 15 Mar 2013 10:28:40 GMT","date":"Fri, 1
5 Mar 2013 10:28:40 GMT","connection":"close"}
BODY: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;ff12017&#46;1363343320&#46;11402929
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: You are creating a POST request, to just get the google page use method : 'GET'. POST is used for authentication, or server interaction. Since you did not send anything meaningful you got 'Bad Request'